# Decouple Service and Model in a Framework

Tags: java

In my framework I have a class `PhonecallerService`. Currently the users of my framework have to create a new `PhonecallerService` for each person they want to call, because the service depends on `PhonecallerCredentials`. The thing is, users should not call the `PhonecallerService::callPhone` method. They should just define a state, where the `PhonecallerService::callPhone` method is called.

*PhonecallerService*

```
package framework
public class PhonecallerService{

    private PhonecallerCredentials phonecallerCredentials;

    public PhonecallerService(PhonecallerCredentials phonecallerCredentials){
        this.phonecallerCredentials = phonecallerCredentials;
    }

    public void callPhone(){
        // use phonecallerCredentials to call
    }
}
```

*ClientClass*

```
package client
public class ClientClass extends FrameworkClass{

    public Actions provideActions(Actions action){
        return action.put(STATE.ERROR, PhonecallerServiceFactory.create(new PhonecallerCredentials(x, y));
    }
}
```

Is there a way to create an actual `PhonecallerService` like below? I have no idea how I can get the connection between `PhonecallerCredentials` and `PhonecallerService` in my framework, when I use the approach below.

*PhonecallerService*

```
package framework
@Service
public class PhonecallerService{
    public void callPhone(PhonecallerCredentials phonecallerCredentials){
        // use phonecallerCredentials to call
    }
}
```

*ClientClass*

```
package client
public class ClientClass extends FrameworkClass{

    public Actions provideActions(Actions action){
        return action.put(STATE.ERROR, new PhonecallerCredentials(x, y);
    }
}
```